# Cascade delete in EF5.0 code first approach parent table not deleting properly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I've defined cascade delete to the child model using Entity Framework 5.0 code first approach.
Now when performing the delete operation to the parent table record, then the corresponding child table records not getting deleted. Child table had a foreign key reference from parent table.
In the below I'm attaching my models code:

```
//"Product" parent class
public class Product
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   [Required]
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string Upc { get; set; }

   public double Height { get; set; }
   public double Width { get; set; }
   public virtual List<ProductImages> ProductImages { get; set; }

   public Product()
   {
       this.ProductImages = new List<ProductImages>();
   }
}


//"ProductImages" child class
public class ProductImages
{     
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   public string Upc { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Upc")]
   public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public short Orientation { get; set; }
}

//Cascade delete constraint
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
              .HasMany(t => t.ProductImages)
              .WithRequired()
              .HasForeignKey(d => d.Upc)
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

While deleting record I'm getting the following error at
`context.SaveChanges();`

**Error**

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more
>   of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relati
>   onship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-
>   key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreig
>   n-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object
>   must be deleted.

Can any one please help me how to delete at a time the parent table record and child table record?

Thanks,
Sampath.

Comment: Can you show the code how you delete the parent? (Click on "edit" link below your question)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is incorrect. Instead of `.WithRequired()` without parameter you must supply an expression for the inverse navigation property `ProductImages.Product`:

```
.WithRequired(d => d.Product)
```

You must use the parameterless version of `WithRequired` *only if* your entity does *not* have an inverse navigation property.

Comment: Hi, i've tried by modifying the above line of code. still i'm getting same problem. please help me
Thanks,sampath